# Update TableAdapter from multiple/joined tables in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

`Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.` 
Occurs when updating multiple & joined tables in a `DataGridView` using `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` method. How do I solve this kind of situation where I wanted to update my data directly from a `DataGridView`?

Here is some code (assumed connected to DB):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt;
SqlCommandBuilder cb;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2 WHERE table2.Id = table1.Id";

        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, db.con);
        dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

private void updateDataGridView() 
    {
        try
        {
            cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection for open the connection.
So, you can add the MultipleActiveResultSets=true property to your connection string and try this.